# How to store the quantity in the $regTypes array?

Tags: php, laravel

I want to have an array with the info about each registration type associated with a registration. For example if for the registration with id "1" the user selected two registration types of type "General" and one of the type "Plus" the $regTypes array should have this content with 2 item:

```
'registrationTypes' => [
    [
        'name' => 'general',
        'price' => '5',
        'quantity' => '2'
    ],
    [
        'name' => 'plus',
        'price' => '10',
        'quantity' => '1'
    ]
]
```

The registration_types table have the name and the price. So I have this query to get some info about a registration in a conference.

```
$registration = Registration
 ::with('conference', 'Conference.registrationTypes')->where('id', 1)->first();
```

And then I have this code to create the array with the necessary info:

```
$regTypes = [];
foreach($registration->conference->registrationTypes as $key=>$registrationType){
    $regTypes  [
        'regType' => [
            'name' => $registration->conference->registrationTypes[$key]['name'],
            'price' => $registration->conference->registrationTypes[$key]['price']
        ]
    ];
}
```

My doubt is how to also store the quantity in the $regTypes array. Because the quantity is not stored in the database.

Maybe to get the quantity is necessary to do antoher query. With this code below:

```
$registrationTypeDetails = Registration::with('participants:id,registration_type_id,registration_id')->find($regID);

        //dd($registrationTypeDetails);

        $type_counts = [];
        foreach ($registrationTypeDetails->participants as $p) {
            $name = $p->registration_type->name;
            if (!isset($type_counts[$name])) {
                $type_counts[$name] = 0;
            }
            $type_counts[$name]++;
        }

        dump($type_counts);
```

The `$type_counts` shows the quantity of each registration type associated with the registration:

```
array:2 [▼
  "general" => 2
  "plus" => 1
]
```

Do you know how to use this `$type_counts` content to store the quantity properly in the `$regTypes` array?

Answer (score 0):

To directly answer your question (IE not change the controller code, just "use this `$type_counts` content to store the quantity properly in the `$regTypes` array"), I'm hopeful this should work for you:

```
$regTypes = [];
foreach($registration->conference->registrationTypes as $key=>$registrationType){
  $typeName = $registration->conference->registrationTypes[$key]['name'];
  $regTypes  [
    'regType' => [
        'name' => $typeName,
        'price' => $registration->conference->registrationTypes[$key]['price'],
        'quantity' => $type_counts[$typeName]
    ]
  ];
}
```

Basically just pulling the count from the `$type_counts` array based on the name of the Registration Type being the key that you added in the `foreach ($registrationTypeDetails->participants as $p)` loop.

Depending upon what you are after, it might be easier just to loop on the registration types, rather than go through `$registration->conference->registrationTypes`.  This way you don't have duplicates.  But that assumes you don't want duplicates :)

Answer (score 0):

I hope this code useful for you .If you need the number of participants in any type, you can use the following code:

```
$registration = Registration::with('conference','Conference.registrationTypes','Conference.registrationTypes.participants')
        ->where('id',$regID)->first();


$result=$registration->conference->registrationTypes->each(function ($item, $key) use($registration) {
        $item['try_count']=$item->participants->count();
    });

dd($result->toArray());
```

I added the `try_count` variable to the final result:

```
array:2 [▼
  0 => array:6 [▼
    "id" => 1
    "name" => "general"
    "price" => 0
    "conference_id" => 1
    "try_count" => 8
    "participants" => array:8 [▼
      0 => array:5 [▶]
      1 => array:5 [▶]
      2 => array:5 [▶]
      3 => array:5 [▶]
      4 => array:5 [▶]
      5 => array:5 [▶]
      6 => array:5 [▶]
      7 => array:5 [▶]
    ]
  ]
  1 => array:6 [▼
    "id" => 2
    "name" => "plus"
    "price" => 1
    "conference_id" => 1
    "try_count" => 5
    "participants" => array:5 [▼
      0 => array:5 [▶]
      1 => array:5 [▶]
      2 => array:5 [▶]
      3 => array:5 [▶]
      4 => array:5 [▶]
    ]
  ]
]
```